# How to combine javascript function and jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I'm having a code to delete a record using jQuery Ajax and PHP. I'm having a doubt in calling the confirmation call from the user and upon confirmation do the further deletion. My Confirmation function is in JAvascript and my ajax function is in jQuery. Then how should I merge these two functions such that first the alert will come and only upon confirmation the Ajax function should get execute. For youir reference I'm putting below the HTML to I used to call the ajax function and the two functions:
Please help me to solve this issue.

HTML code:

```
<a id ="12002" href="#" class="c-icn c-remove delete_question"  title="Delete question"> Delete</a>
```

Javascript Confirmation function:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ConfirmDelete() {
  var ans=confirm("Are you sure to delete this question?");
  if(!ans) {
      return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

JQuery Ajax function is as follows:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.delete_question',function() { 
        var question_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).closest('tr').hide();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'match_question.php',
            data:{'request_type':'ajax', 'op':'delete','question_id':question_id},
            success: function(data) { 
              if(data=="YES") {
                    alert("Question has been deleted");
              }

            });
        });
});
```

Now can you help me in calling the confirmation function first and only upon receiving confirmation from the user execute further ajax function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the jQuery click handler first call the `ConfirmDelete` method... if it returns false return and ignore further steps

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.delete_question', function () {
        if (ConfirmDelete() === false) {
            return;
        }
        var question_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).closest('tr').hide();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'match_question.php',
            data: {
                'request_type': 'ajax',
                    'op': 'delete',
                    'question_id': question_id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "YES") {
                    alert("Question has been deleted");
                }

            }
        });
    });
});
```

there is no need to write it as a separate function, you can simplify it as

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.delete_question', function () {
        if (!confirm("Are you sure to delete this question?")) {
            return;
        }
        var question_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).closest('tr').hide();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'match_question.php',
            data: {
                'request_type': 'ajax',
                    'op': 'delete',
                    'question_id': question_id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "YES") {
                    alert("Question has been deleted");
                }

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using your javascript function with in the jquery function:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.delete_question',function() { 
    var ans=confirm("Are you sure to delete this question?");
    if(ans) {
       var question_id = $(this).attr('id');
       $(this).closest('tr').hide();

       $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'match_question.php',
           data:{'request_type':'ajax', 'op':'delete','question_id':question_id},
           success: function(data) { 
                    if(data=="YES") {
                       alert("Question has been deleted");
                     }

       });

    }
   });

 });
```